How to migrate Blob handling from dart:js to package:web in Flutter Web?
I'm currently transitioning my Flutter Web app to leverage JS functions via the package:web instead of dart:js and similar libraries. However, I've hit a roadblock where the JSArray<JSAny> type isn't resolving correctly. Below is the complete code snippet:
@JS()
library image;

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:web/web.dart';
import 'dart:js_interop';
import 'dart:convert';

@JS('setImage')
external JSPromise _setImage(Blob data); // defined in .js file

void setImage(String data) {
  final blob = Blob(
    // JSArray<JSAny> is required here.
    JsUint8List.from(Uint8List.fromList(base64Decode(data))),
    BlobPropertyBag(type: 'image/png'),
  );
  _setImage(blob);
}

extension type JsUint8List._(Uint8List _) implements JSArray<JSAny> {
  JsUint8List.from(this._);
}

The runtime error I'm encountering is:
Error: The representation type 'Uint8List' of extension type 'JsUint8List' must be either a subtype of the representation type 'JSArray/*1*/<Object?>' of the implemented extension type 'JSArray/*2*/<JSAny>' or a subtype of 'JSArray/*2*/<JSAny>' itself.

Could someone provide guidance on how to properly convert between Dart's Uint8List and Blob using the new package:web?
I attempted to create a Blob using package:js/js.dart, among others.
@JS()
library image;

// ignore: depend_on_referenced_packages
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
// ignore: depend_on_referenced_packages
import 'package:js/js.dart';
// ignore: avoid_web_libraries_in_flutter
import 'dart:js_util';
// ignore: avoid_web_libraries_in_flutter
import 'dart:html' as html;

@JS('setImage')
external _setImage(html.Blob data);

void setImage(String data) {
  final blob = html.Blob([Uint8List.fromList(base64Decode(data))], 'image/png');
  _setImage(blob);
}

The code has executed successfully. However, I aim to implement it using the new package:web. I referred to this page and to another source (specifically about extension types).

Did you find a solution? I am curious too.

@progNewbie No, I didn't. I'm still waiting for the answer.

You can define the Blob class in Dart for JavaScript interop using the @JS annotation. Below is an example where I've added two arguments. You can refer to the Blob documentation and complete them if necessary. However, this should be sufficient for basic use cases:
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:js_interop';

@JS("Blob")
extension type Blob._(JSObject _) implements JSObject {
  external factory Blob(JSArray<JSArrayBuffer> blobParts, JSObject? options);
  
  factory Blob.fromBytes(List<int> bytes) {
    final data = Uint8List.fromList(bytes).buffer.toJS;
    return Blob([data].toJS, null);
  }
  
  external JSArrayBuffer? get blobParts;
  external JSObject? get options;
}



To create Blob as PNG image data, I had to give options with final options = {'type': 'image/png'}.jsify() as JSObject; in the factory constructor.

You can try this


@JS()
library image;

import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:web/web.dart';

@JS('getImage')
external JSPromise<Blob> _getImage();

Future<String> getImage() async {
  final Blob imageData = await _getImage().toDart;


  final Completer<String> completer = Completer<String>();
  final FileReader reader = FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(imageData); 
  reader.onLoadEnd.listen((_) {
    final dataUrl = reader.result as String;
    final base64String = dataUrl.split(',')[1]; 
    completer.complete(base64String);
  });
  reader.onError.listen((error) => completer.completeError(error));
  return completer.future;
}

@JS('setImage')
external JSPromise _setImage(Blob data);

void setImage(String base64Data) {
  final Uint8List data = base64Decode(base64Data);


  final Blob blob = Blob([data]); 
  _setImage(blob);
}




This code has compile errors (import errors in @JS and type error at Blob([data])).

Can you try change import to this ->
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:js/js.dart';
Though I am not sure about Blob([data]) type error

Thank you for your answers. However it uses previous interop as dart:html and package:js. I would like to migrate to new interop.
